# How much is the fuel consumption of a Tecnam P2002?

Tags: fuel

So I'm gonna have the training for PPL and I wanted to know the fuel consumption of a Tecnam P2002 aircraft. But I couldn't find any aircraft information for this particular plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your search based on the engine model, Rotax 912S2, not the aircraft.

However you can work it out easily for any aircraft and engine if you remember that carbureted gasoline engines burn about .4 to .45 lbs/hp/hr. The rotax is pretty efficient so you can use .4 (old air cooled direct drive carbureted engines like Lycomings are closer to .45).  So at 75hp in cruise, that's 30 lb/hr at cruise or 4.4 US gal/hr or about 17l/hr.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: I said 4 to 4.5 lbs... mistake... corrected to .4 and .45.